# How to get Chart Layout number in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I know Chart layout can be changed using `ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (9)`.

How can I get the layout number of a chart?

I got ChartStyle and ChartType using this:

```
With ActiveChart
    Debug.Print .ChartStyle
    Debug.Print .ChartType
End With
```

Hypothetically, I should get the chart layout number using something like this:

```
Debug.Print ActiveChart.Layout ' It should print 9 in this case
```

I tried the above code, but didn't work. Excel forums only mention how to apply the layout, but not how to get the layout number. Please help.

Comment: If you need to change it to a certain number, you can just apply it otherwise what's the purpose of obtaining that information?

Comment: @Mech I need to conduct an exam where candidates have to apply a certain chart layout. I need to check if a candidate has applied the specific layout.

Comment: There is no `.Layout` property of the `Chart` object. That layout feature was a way to apply a few specific formats to a chart, but it's not as formal as chart types or styles. Frankly I find it more distracting than helpful, and I prefer not to show it or especially test for it. (I'm an expert at Excel, but I suspect I would do poorly in many tests which include things like this.)